# What method does this eventually call: do_action_ref_array( 'parse_query', array( &$this ) );

Tags: wp-query, parse

I'm looking at this line of code at the end of `public function parse_query` in query.php:

```
do_action_ref_array( 'parse_query', array( &$this ) );
```

Does this simply end up calling the `parse_query` method/function again at some point in the future?

The reason I ask is 'cos I'm trying to track down why WordPress is returning is_404() as true. And it only turns true **after this line of code**.

Comment: Have you disabled all plugins and/or tried with one of the default themes to see if you still get a 404. The line of code you added is used like `add_action( 'parse_query', 'my_function' )`

Comment: The number of times people say this - there should be a 1-click "disable plugins / use default themes" in the WordPress dashboard. Yes, tried this and still a 404.

Comment: I didn't add that line of code. It's in WP Core.

Comment: I meant the line you added to the question. `do_action_ref_array('parse_query')` is a hook, and it is hooked into by using `add_action('parse_query', 'function')`

Comment: Gotcha - so something could be calling some `'function'` using this hook. And that's what's changing the query. If so, what else could be calling the hook after using the default theme and disabling all plugins?

Comment: Is WordPress returning 404 for all pages?

Comment: Old Permalink structure ("/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/"): `/parent-category/page` ends up redirecting to /page which works. BUT, when I use a new Permalink structure  "/%category%/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/" then /parent-category/page gives me a 404.